# Drawing boundary through DEM of glacier valley using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem

I want to calculate/draw the boundary extent in Glacier valley with the help of DEM.

Can you please guide me which is the best tools in ArcGIS and steps to calculate.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! You may notice that I have removed your email address from your question.  This is because our focussed Q&A format is designed not for one-to-one offline discussion that would help only you, but to act as a learning opportunity for our whole community and any future visitors to our site.  To learn more about how GIS SE works I recommend our [tour] and [ask] page.

Comment: @Ateeq Can you give us a little more detail. For example what is the source and resolution of the DEM? To do what you are looking to do, you may need a high quality DEM like one generated by LiDAR. It's hard to say without more information.

Comment: Are you interested in delineating the glacier using manual editing/drawing?  Using a DEM thresholding technique? Or, possibly, are you looking for an automated delineation approach (e.g. supervised classification)?